# prettify_json.rb not working from command line in zsh

Tags: ruby, zsh

I keep getting `Command Not Found: prettify_json.rb` from the command line.  I'm using `zsh` and `rvm` so, I'm not sure if it has something to do with the paths setting in my `.zshrc`. I've compared it to some other questions here with similar problems and I'm not able to see an issue.

here is the `.zshrc` file:

```
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh
alias vi="vim"

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
source ~/.git-flow-completion.zsh

export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Comment: I have a similar problem using rbenv. I get "rbenv: prettify_json.rb: command not found" which is not that interesting. More interesting is that I also get: "The `prettify_json.rb' command exists in these Ruby versions: 1.9.3-p125" So, I am wondering if the latest 1.9.3-p194 is missing this utility of has it broken in some small way?

Answer (score 3):

The json gem may not have shipped with prettify_json.rb. But it is available in the json-utils gem. Try `gem install json-utils`